# Showing alert on second occurrence

Tags: javascript

I have given a call for the below javascript function on drop down selection.
Basically what my requirement is that ,there can be a lot of vndrCd .
But,When ever the first time vndrCd is "SFGL", alert should not open .
If "SFGL is coming second time then an alert should come . I am not able to put this condition as the call to the method is at every click . Is there a way I can achive this .

```
function GetOptions(var1) {
    varId = var1.id;

    var vndrNbrCdList = document.getElementById('TouchCellDetailForm:vendorNbrCodeList').value;
    var splitVndrList = vndrNbrCdList.split(',');

    if (var1.value == '0') {
        varhiddBox.value = '0';
        return;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < splitVndrList.length; j++) {
        if (splitVndrList[j].split('-')[0] == (var1.value)) {
            var vndrCd = splitVndrList[j].split('-')[1];
            break;
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem("vendorName", vndrCd);
    var vendorName1 = localStorage.getItem("vendorName");
    if (vendorName1 == 'SFGL') {
        alert("Salesforce vendor has already been selected.Please select some other vendor");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure to hold a private variable to indicate whether `'SFGL'` has been encountered or not:

```
function GetOptionsHelp() {
    'use strict';

    let called = false;

    return function GetOptions(var1) {
        // ... your code block
    if (vendorName1 == 'SFGL') {
        if (called) {
            alert("Salesforce vendor has already been selected.Please select some other vendor");
        } else {
            called = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call the function like this `GetOptionsHelp()(var1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this as an easy solution:

```
(function () {
        var firstTimeFlag = true;

        function GetOptions(var1) {
            varId = var1.id;

            var vndrNbrCdList = document.getElementById('TouchCellDetailForm:vendorNbrCodeList').value;
            var splitVndrList = vndrNbrCdList.split(',');

            if (var1.value == '0') {
                varhiddBox.value = '0';
                return;
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < splitVndrList.length; j++) {
                if (splitVndrList[j].split('-')[0] == (var1.value)) {
                    var vndrCd = splitVndrList[j].split('-')[1];
                    break;
                }
            }

            localStorage.setItem("vendorName", vndrCd);
            var vendorName1 = localStorage.getItem("vendorName");
            if (vendorName1 == 'SFGL') {                    
                if(!firstTimeFlag) {
                    alert("Salesforce vendor has already been    selected.Please select some other vendor");                        
                } 
                firstTimeFlag = false;
            }

        }
}());
```

Comment: How do I give a call for this function ??

Comment: It will be called at the start of application automatically. This type of functions are known as IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression).